# I am writing an Express app and I would like to toggle the isSupervisor boolean property on my schema using a checkbox

Tags: express, checkbox

I am trying to setup a checkbox in an express app editing form. The checkbox will toggle whether or not an employee is a supervisor. I have set up isSupervisor to be a Boolean in my Mongoose Schema. I can't target the checkbox with document.querySelector as its telling me document is not defined. I have the feeling i need to somehow extract the value from the checkbox in the route that my form is sending to, but I'm not sure how to target the checkbox to extract the value. Can anyone help?

```
//employee edit route for form to submit to
app.put('/employees/:id', async (req, res) => {
    
    const { id } = req.params;
    const employee = await Employee.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, {runValidators: true});
    res.redirect(`/employees/${employee._id}`);
})
```

Schema

```
Schema

const employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    employeeId: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    position: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: () => Date.now()
    },
    isSupervisor: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    }, 
   })
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Submitting an HTML form like

```html
<form method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="...">
  <input type="checkbox" name="isSupervisor"/>
  <input type="text" name="firstName"/>
  ...
</form>
```

will result in the following request

| If checkbox is | Request payload as string | `req.body.isSupervisor` | `!!req.body.isSupervisor` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| checked | `isSupervisor=on&firstName=...` | `"on"` | `true` |
| unchecked | `firstName=...` | `undefined` | `false` |

So the value is automatically included in the POST request, you need not "extract" it.

In order for the mongoose model to accept the value, you probably need to convert `req.body.isSupervisor` into the Boolean value `!!req.body.isSupervisor`, as shown in the fourth table column.

Comment: Hi Heiko, thanks for answering, i tried your solution and I am getting the following message "Cast to Boolean failed for value "on" (type string) at path "isSupervisor" because of "CastError".  any ideas what is wrong? Thanks again

Comment: See my augmented answer.

Comment: Thanks again Heiko, sorry i am just starting out with this. I will try to  convert req.body.isSupervisor into the Boolean value !!req.body.isSupervisor somehow.

Comment: `req.body.isSupervisor = !!req.body.isSupervisor` before calling `Employee.findByIdAndUpdate`.

Comment: Heiko, thank you so so much! I had been trying something similar for hours but just slightly incorrectly formulated or in the wrong place each time. Thanks once more!